# Programming Challenge using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a follow up to a previous question which seems to have confused people so I'll purify it a bit. Here is some markup.

```
<div class="button width120 height30 iconLeft colorRed"></div>
<div class="button width180 height20 iconPlus colorBlue"></div>
<div class="button width200 height10 iconStar colorGreen"></div>
<div class="button width110 height60 iconBack colorOrange"></div>
```

The challenge is to fill in the code in the following.

```
$(".button").each(function(){

    // Get the width from the class

    // Get the height from the class

    // Get the icon from the class

    // Get the color from the class

});
```

Now, I know that you shouldn't use classes this way so I'm not looking for alternative ways of doing it, this is an experiment and I'm interested to know if it's possible to do it this way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like:

```
$(".button").each(function(){
    var classNames = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
    var width, height;
    for(int i = 0; i < classNames.length; i++) {
        var className = classNames[i];
        if(className.indexOf('width') > -1) {
            width = className.substring(5, className.length - 1);
        } else if(className.indexOf('height') > -1) {
            height = className.substring(6, className.length - 1);
        } // etc. etc.
    }
});
```

Or have I misunderstood what you were asking?

Comment: Substr wont quite work, since the height and width could be longer

Comment: eh? it uses className.length - 1, so the value can be of any length.

Comment: I think you have understood the question :)

Would this still work if the width wasn't there when the page loaded but I added it using $(".button").addClass("width250");

Would the new class have been added to the class attribute?

Comment: @jonhobbs: Yes it would, at least if you run this code *after* you add the class. When you call addClass, jQuery simply modifies the className property of the element.

Answer (score 3):

I found this answer which looks very robust...

```
$(".button").each(function(el){
    classStr = el.className;
    classes = classStr.split(' ');

    // Loop through classes and find the one that starts with icon

});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a terrible idea, but since you seem to already know that, here's the code:

```
$(".button").each( function() {
  var width, height, color, icon;
  $.each( $(this).attr('class').split(), function( cls ) {
    if( cls.match("^width") ) { width = cls.split('width').pop(); }
    else if( cls.match("^height") ) { height = cls.split('height').pop(); }
    else if( cls.match("^icon") ) { icon = cls.split('icon').pop(); }
    else if( cls.match("^color") ) { color = cls.split('color').pop(); }
  } );
  console.log( "width: " + width );
  console.log( "height: " + height );
  console.log( "icon: " + icon );
  console.log( "color: " + color );
});
```

Comment: Nice :) (10 chars? what if all I want is a smiley!)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".button").each( function() {
    var classStr = this.className;
    var classes = {}
    classStr.replace( /(width|height|icon|color)([a-z0-9]+)/gi,
        function( str, key, val ) {
            classes[key] = val;
        }
    );
    console.log( classes );
});

/*
 * {
 *     width:  '120',
 *     height: '30',
 *     icon:   'Left',
 *     color:  'Red'
 * }
 */
```

Comment: Nice work, but you didn't extract out just the values. I'm pretty sure that's what he wanted. So, you're like halfway there.

Answer (score 0):

I like to solve some challenges in silly ways. :D This is a very unelegant, inefficient and not very safe solution. But i had fun writing it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <head>

    <script src="jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        $(".button").each(function(){
          var div = $(this)
          div.css({"border":"1px solid black"});
          var classes = div.attr('class').split(' ').slice(1);
          classes.forEach( function (element) {
            div.append(/(width|height)(\d+)|(icon|color)(\S+)/.exec(element).filter(function (element) {return !!element} ).slice(1).join(": ").concat("<br>" ) )
          })
        })
      });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="button width120 height30 iconLeft colorRed"></div>
    <div class="button width180 height20 iconPlus colorBlue"></div>
    <div class="button width200 height10 iconStar colorGreen"></div>
    <div class="button width110 height60 iconBack colorOrange"></div>


  </body>

</html>
```

Ohh, and it doesn't work in every browser. ;)